# Find $\cos(t)$ if $\sin(t)=\frac{x}{x+1}$

Tags: trigonometry

I know that this is a very elementary trigonometry question, but for some reason I can't understand what it is asking. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: Use: $\cos^2x = 1 - \sin^2x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The question asks to find the value of $\cos(t)$ if $\sin(t)$ is given. Now among the numerous trigonometric relations, one is relevant here:

$$\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1.$$

Comment: I had figured it out. Thanks.